# How to pass Id from one razor page to another razor page with mutliple tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

im having a razor page with multiple forms in multiple tabs.When i submit a form it will go to the next tab with another. I want to pass two ids from first form to second form (which is razor page).Here is the code.

This is function used for submittig the first form StaffDetails.cshtml.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostInsertStaffDetailsAsync(StaffDetails StaffDetails)
        {
            ShowTypeOfEmployee = new SelectList(_context.TypeOfEmployees, "TypeOfEmployee", "TypeOfEmployee");
            ShowEmploymentType = new SelectList(_context.EmploymentTypes, "EmploymentType", "EmploymentType");            
            DeptName = new SelectList(_context.Department.OrderBy(e => e.DeptName), "DeptName", "DeptName");
            EmpCategories = new SelectList(_context.EmploymentCategory.OrderBy(e => e.EmpCategories), "EmpCategories", "EmpCategories");
            EmpStatus = new SelectList(_context.EmploymentStatus.OrderBy(e => e.EmpStatus), "EmpStatus", "EmpStatus");
            RegularOrTemporary = new SelectList(_context.RegTemp.OrderBy(e => e.RegularOrTemporary), "RegularOrTemporary", "RegularOrTemporary");
            IncentivePlans = new SelectList(_context.IncentivePlan, "IncentivePlans", "IncentivePlans");

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                await _context.StaffDetails.AddAsync(StaffDetails);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                
                int StaffID = StaffDetails.StaffID;
                //HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("StaffID", StaffID);
                //HttpContext.Session.SetString("EmpID", StaffDetails.EmpID);
                TempData["EmpID"] = StaffDetails.EmpID;
                TempData["StaffID"] = StaffID;

                var foldername = StaffDetails.EmpID.ToString();
                var DirectoryPath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Documents", "EmployeeAttachments", foldername);
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(DirectoryPath))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(DirectoryPath);
                }
                return new OkResult();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ajax function for navigating to next form in the next tab.

```
function StaffDetailsCompleted(event) {            
            if (event.responseText != "") {
                $("#StaffDetails").html(event.responseText);
            } else {
                alert("Staff Details Has Been Added Successfully");
                $('a[href="#Biodata"]').tab('show');                
            }
        }
```

The second form Biodata.cshtml

```
@page
@model Contractor_HRMS.Pages.Staff.Onboarding.BioDataModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<br />
<form asp-page-handler="InsertBioData" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="BioDataCompleted">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <input asp-for="StaffBioData.StaffID" id="StaffID" type="hidden" value='@TempData["StaffID"]' />
            <input asp-for="StaffBioData.EmpID" id="EmpId" type="hidden" value='@TempData["EmpID"]' />
            <!-- First Name -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.IdenEmpFname" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.IdenEmpFname" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.IdenEmpFname" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Last Name -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.IdenEmpLname" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.IdenEmpLname" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.IdenEmpLname" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Address -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.Address" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.Address" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.Address" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Photo -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label-staff"><b>Photo</b></label>
                <input type="file" asp-for="StaffPhoto" class="form-control-staff" multiple style="border:1px solid white;margin-right:20px" />
            </div>

            <!-- Gender -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.Gender" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffBioData.Gender" asp-items="Model.StaffGender" class="form-control-staff">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.Gender" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Date of Birth -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.Dob" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.Dob" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.Dob" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Race -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.Race" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.Race" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.Race" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Religion -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.Religion" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffBioData.Religion" asp-items="Model.StaffReligion" class="form-control-staff">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.Religion" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Nationality -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.Nationality" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.Nationality" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.Nationality" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Ethnicity -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.Ethnicity" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.Ethnicity" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.Ethnicity" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            

            <!-- Emergency Contact -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label-staff"><b>Emergency Contact:</b></label><br />

                <!-- Emergency Contact Name-->
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.EmergencyContactName" class="control-label-staff" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.EmergencyContactName" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.EmergencyContactName" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                <br /><br />

                <!-- Emergency Contact No-->
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.EmergencyContactNo" class="control-label-staff" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.EmergencyContactNo" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.EmergencyContactNo" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                <br /><br />

                <!-- Emergency Contact Relation-->
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.EmergencyContactRelation" class="control-label-staff" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.EmergencyContactRelation" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.EmergencyContactRelation" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                <br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.LastModifiedBy" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.LastModifiedBy" class="form-control" value="jteena" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.LastModifiedBy" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                <label asp-for="StaffBioData.LastModifiedTimestamp" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffBioData.LastModifiedTimestamp" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffBioData.LastModifiedTimestamp" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:550px;">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
```

what happens here is im not able to set values for hidden variables STaffID and EmpID using TempData.
Am i doing anything wrong.Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the content under each tab is already filled when the details page is loaded, some changes made later will not be reflected. You can request the next page again in the completed function to refresh it.

```
function StaffDetailsCompleted(event) {
    if (event.responseText != "") {
        $("#StaffDetails").html(event.responseText);
    } else {
        alert("Staff Details Has Been Added Successfully");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Staff/Onboarding/Biodata",
            type: "get",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#Biodata").html(result);
                $('a[href="#Biodata"]').tab('show');
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @mj1313, I have one problem now.After adding details, it will focus to the current tab, but the modal is not auto-closing. Im not able to add anything,need to reload the site again.

Comment: @Teena, can you show the handler for Add and Edit?

Comment: Hi @mj1313,I have edited your answer .Please check.

Comment: @Teena - I rejected [your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27977057) which edited this answer to add the handlers. I believe that mj1313 would have meant for you to edit your question to add the handlers instead.